# Mostrar HTML e permitir abrir link no browser

Tags: ionic

Estou atualizando um app feito em Ionic3 para o Ionic5.

Existe uma página que exibe um HTML vindo do backend através de `<div [innerHTML]="conteudoHtml"></div>`. Neste HTML pode haver elementos `<a href="http://urlqualquer" />`.

Acontece que ao clicar nestes links o Ionic não faz como na versão anterior, onde ele abria o link no browser (acredito que agora ele esteja lidando como se fosse uma rota).

Como fazer isso nesta nova versão?

Comment: Abrir no browser do usuário ou abrir ou no inappbrowser (plugin para cordova/ionic)? Se não tiver o inappbrowser ele não vai funcionar se eu não me engano. Instalou o inappbrowser? É cordova ou inappbrowser?

Comment: Na versão anterior ele abre no próprio browser do usuário. Eu até poderia usar o inappbrowser ou o browsertab, mas acontece que o HTML já vem pronto com os links, imagens, etc.

Comment: Não funciona, eu já testei adicionando o target diretamente no HTML. No teste via browser funciona, no Android (emulador e smartphone) não.

Comment: acabei de instalar a ultima versão do Ionic (6.17.1), criei um APK, instalei, funcionou perfeitamente. Não precisei instalar plugins extras e nem fazer nada no HTML, não precisei do target, mesmo assim funcionou, estou usando o Android11

Comment: E vc tem as rotas configuradas? app-routing.module.ts

Comment: instalei cru e apenas adicione um link em uma DIV simples na tela inicial usando `[innerHTML]`, não modifiquei, não adicionei plugins. Está tudo exatamente como é o padrão.

Comment: Criei um projeto sidemenu, adicionei uma nova página, a mesma forma de navegação e realmente funcionou... :( Vou ter que instalar cada plugin utilizado no app para descobrir quem está me sacaneando. :((

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver adicionando um event listener ao elemento que irá chamar uma função para abrir o link pelo plugin [Browser Tab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser-tab)

***pag.html***

```
<div #container></div>
```

***pag.ts***

```
  @ViewChild('container', {static: false}) _container: ElementRef;

  constructor(private browser:BrowserTab) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    //carregando o conteudo html vindo do back end
    this._container.nativeElement.innerHTML=conteudoHTML;
    let elementos=Array.prototype.slice.call(this._container.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("a"));
    elementos.forEach(a => {
      //em cada elemento <a> eu removo o href e adiciono uma chamado ao método para abertura da url
      let href=a.getAttribute("href");
      a.removeAttribute("href");
      a.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        this.openUrlExterna(href);
      })
    });
  }

  openUrlExterna(url){
    this.browser.isAvailable().then(isAvailable=>{
      if (isAvailable){
        this.browser.openUrl(url);
      }else{
        console.log("Browser NOT available");
      }
    });
  }
```